# Clarification needed

Tags: certification

A product has a base price of $30 and a special price of $25. Tiered price discount for this product is $20 for 5 products and there's also a catalog rule active of 25% discount for this product. What will the product price shown on product detail page?

A. $15

B. $22.5

C. $25

D. $18.75

How do you guys think what is the right answer to this question?

Any ideas?

Comment: B) $22.5  is the right answer

Comment: For which Certification exam does this question has been asked @Jack

Comment: @Jack Associate Developer?

Comment: M2 Profesional Developer

Comment: did you wrote that exam (or) preparing ?

Comment: It's confusing bcoz community giving a different answer with the same question, see this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/aqfmur/a_product_has_a_base_price_of_30_and_a_special/

Comment: Hi @Jack, it would be better to try this with a Magento installation.

Comment: If the quantity is less then 5 then the product price will be B) $22.5 AND if the product quantity is equal or greater then 5 then the product price will be $20.

Answer (score 2):

**B. $22.5** is the right answer.

**Reason:**

Native Magento doesn't support applying **catalog promotion rules** on **tier prices** and **special prices**.

So, when the catalog promotion rule is applied to the base price, it gets $22.5.

In this case (default case when the quantity of the product is 1), the least price is $22.5, so option B ($22.5) is the correct answer.

I hope it makes sense.

**courtesy:** Answer from Bibhu Asish [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250043/apply-catalog-promotion-rule-on-tier-prices-and-special-prices-in-magento-2)