# How to use tier price promo rule condition in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am using price promo rule condition for tier_price but it is not working.

> can we use tier_price for promo rule condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento can't apply promotion rule to tier price. But this one might help you.

[apply catalog promotion rule on tier prices and special prices in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250043/apply-catalog-promotion-rule-on-tier-prices-and-special-prices-in-magento-2)

What I understand is **Catalog Price Rule** calculate from regular price.

Example: SKU 1001 >> Regular price = 700$, Tier Price 1 qty = 450$

It will show 450$ on frontend.

Then apply **Catalog Price Rule** discount 50$ for this SKU.

It will calculate from 700 - 50 = 650$, So it still 450$ on frontend.

But if you apply **Catalog Price Rule** discount 300$ It will show 400$ on frontend.

Comment: I edit my answer for explain the condition.

Comment: because regular price  is 700$, so the final price = 700 - 300 = 400$. It will show the the cheapest price. In this case (700-300) < 450, so final price = 400.